# Python unittest gives file not found exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a core class which is as below:

```
class GenerateDag(object):

    def __int__(self):
        pass

    def generate_dag(self, manifest: dict):
        """
        :return: bytes of the file passed
        """
        with open('../../resources/dag.py', 'rb') as f:
            return f.read()
```

**TestCase**:

```
def test_generate_dag(self):
        manifest = Mock()
        result = GenerateDag().generate_dag(manifest)
        expected = b"some-byte-content"
        assert result == expected
```

The project structure is as follows:

[image]

When I create an instance something like this `GenerateDag().generate_dag({})` it gives me the proper content of the file as I expected but however, but when I run the test case it gives me the below error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/../IdeaProjects/some-projct/provisioner/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/resources/dag.py'
```

I also tried the below logic in the core class:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent)
conf_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'resources/dag.py')
```

But even this didn't help. So what else I am missing here? I run the tests through `tox`

P.S: My core class is in `src/services`

Comment: You might want to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html to load a resource file. More information at: https://youtu.be/ZsGFU2qh73E

Comment: This didn't help me. I already tried. Considering my project structure can you share a snippet w.r.t it.

Comment: Relative paths are dangerous. Remember they are process-relative paths (not module relative).

Comment: You shouldn't use the filesystem in regular unittests. This violates some rules. Using the filesystem you have an integration test or maybe a system test. The intention of your test is not clear. Technically the other answers are correct. But the real problem might be the concept behind your test. I recommend to read the book _Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns_ by Vladimir Khorikov published 2019.

Comment: I already tried `mock_open`  way where I am mocking the `open` operation by giving the sample data(not the real file content) but the thing is that way I am not testing my actual logic. Therefore, I had to write it this way. Do you think `mock_open` would be the standard way? @buhtz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a tree structure such as:

```
 |
 +- resources
   +-- __init__.py
   +-- data.txt
```

Then to access that information I would use:

```py
from importlib.resources import files

my_resource = files('resources').joinpath('data.txt')
print(my_resource.read_bytes())
```

You might want to put your `resources` directory under `src/services` directories which is your `services` module; in which case it would be:

```
my_resource = files('services.resources').joinpath('data.txt')
```

Comment: But in my case, my resources folder is residing outside `src`. I can't move inside.

Comment: That is what the first example does, it makes resources a module which can be loaded. You need to reference the location of the file to something. The way you have it in your question it is referenced to wherever the current working directory is for the python process that is running and that is why you are seeing different result depending on how you ran python. You can use an environment variable, the `__file__` location, or a module as the reference, but you need something consistent to reference to. The way you have your project structured currently will always cause you pain.

Comment: What would be the ideal way to keep resources folder in?

Comment: It is a resources folder for the services module so I would have thought `src/services/resources` would have been best given what you have shared

Comment: Your import statement should be `from importlib_resources`

Comment: `importlib_resources` is a backport of Python standard library `importlib.resources module` for older Pythons. https://github.com/python/importlib_resources

Comment: for me that only works. `.` doesn't work.